# Meromorphic extensions of $\zeta-$functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Suppose we have a series $\zeta_x(s)=\sum_{n\geq1}x(n)n^{-s},$ where $x=\{x(n)\}_{n\geq1}$ is a bounded sequence.

Clearly, $\zeta_x$ is analytic function for $\Re(s)>1.$

Question: is there a constructive criterion for $\zeta_x$ to be meromorphic?